# jsTree -- Add button in checbox tree

Tags: jquery, button, checkbox, jstree

I created a checkbox tree using jstree, and I would like to add a column of buttons on the right side, for example, "edit" button, which links to another page where you can add more detail about this checkbox item. How should I do this in jstree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jsTreeGrid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid) to achieve what you want. See a sample http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/

Comment: thanks!That's what I'm looking for. But is there any way to get rid of the scroll bar of the tree?

Comment: Because when the checklist goes longer than the page, there will be 2 scroll bars on the right...

Comment: when I use jstreeGrid, the tree always has a scroll bar on the right side, and when you  unfold all the subitems of the tree, another scroll bar appears on the right side of the page. http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/

Comment: I want the tree's scroll bar to disappear, I think one scrollbar (of the page)is enough.

Comment: Never mind my question, I just tested on iphone, the tree's scroll bar won't show up on touch screen. Thank you very much!:)